# How to calculate the sum of particular rows and show in another column in gridview using C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, checkboxlist

I am working on a school ERP project as an ASP.NET web application in which we have a gridview. On my page I want to calculate the sum of cells value row wise  of the gridview but the code which I am using returns two or three times the total of the particular column. Any suggestions on how we can calculate the right total of the particular column?

Note: Here we have one checkbox list which fill from database and the item of chekboxlist are the column of gridview when we checked an item in chekboxlist a column dynamically add gridview and when we checked second item in cheboxlist then second column added int gridview as shown in my figure

[image]

my desired result (output)

[image]

my c# code.

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections;
     using System.Configuration;
     using System.Data;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Security;
     using System.Web.UI;
     using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
     using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
     using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
     using System.Xml.Linq;
     using System.Data.SqlClient;
     namespace egurukul
     {
     public partial class feerecipts : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
       decimal val;
      string _connStr =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             if (!IsPostBack)
              {

               bindgvfeehead();
               BindTableColumns();
              }
          }

       private void BindTableColumns()
        {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Readduedat", conn);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // get the adapter object and attach the command object to it

            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            // fire Fill method to fetch the data and fill into DataTable

            ad.Fill(table);

        }

        chbxlstduedate.DataSource = table;
        chbxlstduedate.DataTextField = "duemonth";
        chbxlstduedate.DataValueField = "duedateid";
        chbxlstduedate.DataBind();

    }

    public void bindgvfeehead()
    {
        SqlConnection
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "readfeehead";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classname", Convert.ToString(ddlclassname.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feecatename", Convert.ToString(ddlstcategory.SelectedItem));
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table);
        gvfeehead.DataSource = table;
        gvfeehead.DataBind();
        con.Close();

    }

    private void GetData()
    {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        // get the connection

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "readfeedetails";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // instantiate the command object to fire
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classname", Convert.ToString(ddlclassname.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feecatename", Convert.ToString(ddlstcategory.SelectedItem));
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // fire Fill method to fetch the data and fill into DataTable

        ad.Fill(table);
        conn.Close();

        // specify the data source for the GridView

        GridView1.DataSource = table;

        // bind the data now

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void chbxlstduedate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in chbxlstduedate.Items)
        {

            if (item.Selected)
            {

                BoundField b = new BoundField();

                b.DataField = item.Text;

                b.HeaderText = item.Text;

                GridView1.Columns.Add(b);



            }


        }

        TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
        tfield.HeaderText = "Total";
        GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield);

        this.GetData();

        bindgvfeehead();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            int j;
            double Total = 0.00;
            for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                Total += GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text != "&nbsp;" ? double.Parse(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text) : 0.000;

            }
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Columns.Count);
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k - 1].Text = Total.ToString("#0.000");


            }

          }

       }
   }
```

my aspx code

```
<div style="float:left">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvfeehead" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" 
                            Font-Size="11px"   BorderWidth="3px" 
                            CellPadding="4" GridLines="both" ShowFooter="True">
                            <RowStyle ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="White" Height="20px" />
                            <Columns>
                               <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>Sr.No </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>  <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>Fee Name </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblfeename" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("feename") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate> <asp:Label ID="lblfeename" CssClass="footer_text" runat="server" Text="Total"></asp:Label></FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" 
                            Font-Size="11px" BorderWidth="3px" 
                            CellPadding="4" GridLines="both" 
                            ShowFooter="True" EnableViewState="false" 
                            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                            <RowStyle ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="White" Height="21px" />
                            <Columns>

                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="true" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        </asp:GridView>

                        </div>



       <div class="duedateheading">
                 <asp:Label ID="lbl_formonth" runat="server" Font-  Bold="True" Text="For Month"></asp:Label>
                         </div>
                 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chbxlstduedate" runat="server"        AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="chbxlstduedate_SelectedIndexChanged">
                 </asp:CheckBoxList>
                         </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're iterating through every row whenever a new row is added to the GridView. Also, you might want to have a look at [`GridViewRowEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Row one which having values returning correct value so the problem may happening on null check try using `Trim()`

```
Total += GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Trim() != "&nbsp;" ? double.Parse(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Trim()) : 0.000;
```

also you need to check whether row index of gridview comming to the loop correctly or not

Comment: Thanks Midhun for reply but it's not working for me it's same result as previous result .any other idea .i think there problem in my loop but i did not understand please let me know if you can